# git svn or git on a svn?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I'm trying to find a way to work with git on top of an svn repo..
We have an svn repo that can't change (we can't just stop using svn).
I want to be able to have a way to work with my team on a centralized repo with git and then, when we're ok to commit this to svn..

I haven't found a way to do this with git svn so i did the following:

- Create a git bare repo to be used as a centralized repo for our git and svn stuff
- Svn clone the svn repo and git commit the first svn clone
- Everyone clones the git repo and commits (git) to that repo
- Svn updates are done on git master branch, result is commited (git) and everyone rebases their git branch on the master
- When everything is done, svn commit the specific files

So basically i was thinking we could use the git repo as a middle man between our interaction with svn while keeping the git cool stuff..

- Does this have any possible dangers?
- Can anyone suggest anything else? (is there a git svn solution to
  this problem?)

Comment: "we can't working with svn" then something in your company is wrong ;) changing to Git is not a problem... SVN is now really dead... don't work on a short solution work on a long solution ;)

Comment: Well when you work on a big company you can't just enforce the "svn is dead"... so you try workarounds

Comment: I know the problem with big company but i don't that if you want you can change the world ;)

Comment: I was pretty successful at using `git-svn` for a few month and my colleagues haven't noticed that. We had a SVN repo (source of truth) and I used `git svn dcommit` to push my changes, when on my local machine I had a full power of git, like topic branches and rebases. When our bosses found that, we switched to Git in a week (1 day for setting the repo, and 4 days to update docs and Jenkins ;) )